# Texture Error When Sculpting in Multires

Tags: mesh, texturing, sculpting

I am very new to multiresolution sculpting (new as in just started this evening) and I've come across an issue. When I'm sculpting with multiresolutions, it looks completely fine in solid mode but I have massive texture issues when I sculpt in viewport shading, where the texture looks completely jumbled (see pic). This goes away if I check off "sculpt base mesh", however once I do that it's essentially impossible for me to sculpt, I drag the mouse but the cursor stays at the beginning, like it's lagging massively. I would ideally like to use multires to get fine details such as veins and stuff, I've so far just been using the subdivision modifier with it set to 3 subdivisions, but that doesn't allow me to get those small details.
As additional context, this is a model of a sim from The Sims 4 that's been ripped from the game, with merge by distance and tris to quads applied (if that impacts it at all).
Thank you in advance!
[image]

Comment: I am not much of a sculpting expert, but everytime I watched people sculpt live, they used the Dyntopo function to create the details you were speaking of. I have never seen anybody sculpt a mesh using the multires modifier, but I have seen them doing it with the Dyntopo function. Did you give this approach a try?